# Call Custom Function from cell that calls YouTube API

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, youtube-api

I have searched a lot for this already, and I honestly can't believe that I haven't been able to find the answer, even if it's "You can't do that".

I have created a bound Google Apps Script Project inside of a Google Sheet. That project contains a function called `getVidViews` source:

```
function getVidViews(id){
 //id = k3y1hJPVavY
 let res = YouTube.Videos.list('statistics',{'id':id});
 return res.items[0].statistics.viewCount;
}
```

If I run this code from the Project Editor IDE and un-comment the line where I set `id`. I'm redirected to authorize oAuth scopes, and the function executes exactly how I want.

However, I want to have a spreadsheet where I have the id in cell `A1` and I want to paste the result of the call in `B1`.

I should be able to accomplish this by pasting an id in A1 and using the formula `=getVidViews(A1)` in `B1`

When I do this, I get the error:

> GoogleJsonResponseException: API call to youtube.videos.list failed
> with error: The request is missing a valid API key.

I cannot figure why it is requesting an API key here, but not in the code editor. Also, I know that Google Apps Scripts create a hidden GCP project, but don't know if I can add an API key to that project for use in this instance.

Please point me in the right direction.

Answer (score 0):

Custom functions [only support certain services](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/sheets/functions#using_apps_script_services) and YouTube isn't one of them.

Here's a [deep dive into custom functions](https://medium.com/geekculture/how-to-build-custom-functions-in-google-sheets-with-google-apps-script-94766c31d8e6?sk=6323c9e0d1694821053b0739ad7ae85f) if you are interested.